# HTML Button with Hyperlink Characteristics

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, right-click

I'm looking for a way to use the functionality of a html button where I can bind the OnClick events and deal with it accordingly but I'm also looking to see if we can have hyperlink functionality for that button so they can right click on it and click "Open in new tab" which will fire off the button event but push it to a new tab.

Does anyone know if this is doable?

Hoping for it to look something like this. Currently this is a button with an image and a span inside of it which has a hover over effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to use the functionality of a html button where I can bind the OnClick events and deal with it accordingly...

You can bind `click` handlers to almost any DOM element.

> ...but I'm also looking to see if we can have hyperlink functionality for that button so they can right click on it and click "Open in new tab" which will fire off the button event but push it to a new tab.

So use an `<a>` element. All you need to do is check which mouse button was used, and that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys are *not* pressed (otherwise the user is trying to open the link in a new tab, or other such shortcut behaviors).

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.button === 0 && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.shiftKey) {
        alert('button was clicked!');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

```css
.btn {
    background-color: #8CF;
    border: 1px solid #00F;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:focus {
    border-color: #000;
}

.btn__icon {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 17px 17px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/" class="btn">
    <img class="btn__icon" src="http://placehold.it/40x40/FFF/000"/>
    <span class="btn__label">Details</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a link styled like a button.  You can set it up to look like a button and set up click events, as well as opening it in a new tab.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try something like this - style the `<a>` as a button (as proposed by previous answers) and then prevent default on click:

HTML

```
<a id = "btn" href = "http://www.google.com">CLICK ME</a>
```

jquery

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7kzdce0s/)

This gives you a click function on the link, prevents the default action, but retains the right click context menu.

Comment: This will prevent users from middle clicking, ctrl clicking, shift clicking, etc.

Comment: The OP only asked to preserve right click to enable the user to select 'open in a new tab'.  Your comment may be correct, but is not relevant to the question.  This does exactly what was asked.

Comment: OP said "I'm also looking to see if we can have hyperlink functionality for that button". Ctrl click, middle click, alt click are all part of hyperlink functionality. Preventing those features is a way to guarantee that power users will *hate* your code.

Comment: You left out the 'so' after 'button' - the hyperlink functionality is required **so** that right click access to 'open in a new tab' is available - there's no suggestion of any other requirement.  You may be right that power users will hate it, but there is nothing in the question to suggest that is of any concern to the OP.   In fact, removing basic left click functionality to a click function suggests that it's not.

Comment: All I can tell you is that you're doing it wrong. If you're going to be defensive about it, that's your choice. If adding one line of code to properly check click events is too much effort, I can't help you.

Comment: Your answer is undoubtedly better for most purposes, but based on the little information in the question, I'm just not prepared to guess what exactly the OP is up to (nor assume more than is clearly requested) - so rather than up or down vote others, I prefer to leave the decision up to the OP.  Go in peace.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the question but I think this is what you mean..

```
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="clickFunction()" value="Click Me!">

<script>
function clickFunction() {
    document.getElementById("button1").onmousedown = function(event) {
        if (event.which == 3) { <!--3 = right click-->
            window.open('target', '_blank'); <!--Opens target in a new tab-->
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I don't *think* that you can change the context menu that pops up to add "Open in new tab" on right click but you can tell how to handle a right click.

Edit: Actually you can change the default context menu I believe but I don't think you can do it without 3rd party libs? Again not sure about that someone else will have to give you a better answer sorry :/

Edit2: After seeing your initial edit I'd agree with @Surreal Dreams. Use styling and make a normal link with an image and hover effect :)